# How to embed DOM element inside template literals

Tags: javascript, dom, reference, template-literals

Is there any way to embed DOM element inside a template string?

```
const btn= document.createElement('button');
btn.addEventListener('click', handler);

someDiv.innerHTML = `
<div>${btn}</div>
`;
```

It just calls HTMLElement's toString function and renders `[object HTMLButtonElement]` instead of actual button

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Element.outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) to get element as string. Note it will not append the real `btn` to `div` it will copy the 
element's html and `eventListener` attached to it will not work.

If you want the copy elements with its function you can use [`cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) and `appendChild()` to insert it to parent.

```js
let somediv = document.querySelector('#somediv');
const btn= document.createElement('button');
btn.innerHTML = 'Click me';
btn.addEventListener('click',(e) => {
  somediv.innerHTML = `<div>${btn.outerHTML}</div>`
  console.log(somediv.innerHTML);
})
document.body.appendChild(btn);
```

```css
#somediv{
  position:absolute;
  top:200px;
  left:200px;
  padding:10px;
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="somediv"></div>
```

Comment: You're losing the event listener the OP bound.

Comment: @ziggy wiggy his question showed what he wanted to get the `html` of element.

Comment: The question doesn't show that. The title and description state that they want to embed the DOM element, not its rendered HTML.

Answer (score 2):

No, the element itself can not be inserted that way. You could serialize it to HTML, but you'll lose any updates you made to the element, such as the event handler.

Instead you could create the entire structure using HTML, then select the `button` to add the listener.

```js
someDiv.innerHTML = `
<div><button>click me</button></div>
`;

someDiv.querySelector("button")
  .addEventListener('click', handler);

var pre = document.querySelector("pre");

function handler(e) {
  pre.textContent += "foo ";
}
```

```html
<div id=someDiv>
</div>
<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

> The Element property `innerHTML` gets or sets the HTML or XML markup contained within the element.

You can not use innerHTML to insert DOM node created with `createElement`, for that you have to use methods like [`ParentNode.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append):

```js
const btn= document.createElement('button');
btn.textContent = 'click';
btn.addEventListener('click', handler);
someDiv.innerHTML = `
<div class="inner"></div>
`;
document.querySelector('.inner').append(btn);
function handler(){alert('clicked')}
```

```html
<div id="someDiv"></div>
```